# Unqueue css file from specific page

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to unqueue style.css file from a specific page.

In my functions.php (child theme) if I add:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'apc_child_desregistra_estilos', 11 );
function apc_child_desregistra_estilos() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'main-styles' );
}
```

It works.

But when I add something like:

```
if (is_front_page()):
wp_dequeue_style( 'main-styles' );
endif;
```

It doesn't.

I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Then it could be because you're not on the front page. So you might be looking for [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) instead?

Comment: Maybe you confuse `is_front_page()` with `is_home()`? See the differences at https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-homepage-conditional/

Comment: Sally, I already tried is_page in all differente kinds (id, title, slug) and still no working. Lee, I'm sure is the is_front_page() because I only want to modify the homepage of the site. I'm almost finding a solution for my problem and I'll post here ASAP. Thanks in advance for y'all help!